# How to make the Website run Index.html file using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to run a index.html file automaticlly once clicking on the folder on the Website using .htaccess

code:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [R,L]
```

and then i restarted apache and refreshed the website but the folder disappeared. i try to wrote the whole link in the Url then comes (Internal Server Error)

i have here centOS 7 as Operating system runing apache

thanks for helping me and excuse please my english :D

best regards 
Jackob

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it works (:

Adding the following to my httpd.conf (if you have access to it) is considered better form, causes less server overhead and has the exact same effect:

```
<Directory /myDirectory>
DirectoryIndex index.html
</Directory>
```